# What does Messaging.InboundEmail.htmlBodyIsTruncated really mean?

Tags: apex-email-service

The apex class `Messaging.InboundEmail` represents an email received by an [Apex Email Service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_inbound_what_is.htm), which is handed to an implementation of the `Messaging.InboundEmailHandler` interface (provided by the developer).  According to [the `InboundEmail` class docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_inbound_inbound.htm?search_text=htmlBodyIsTruncated#apex_classes_email_inbound_inbound), the public boolean property `htmlBodyIsTruncated`, "Indicates whether the HTML body text is truncated (true) or not (false.)"  Likewise, there is a `plainTextBodyIsTruncated` property that, "Indicates whether the plain body text is truncated."

But why would an InboundEmail ever have have a truncated `htmlBody` or `plainTextBody`?  I can find no mention in the documentation, and the two `isXXXBodyTruncated` properties are mentioned nowhere else.  The Apex Email Service docs linked above do state:

> Email services reject email messages and notify the sender if the email (combined body text, body HTML, and attachments) exceeds approximately 10 MB (varies depending on language and character set).

But that's outright rejection, not truncation.  When/why might either of these fields be true?

Comment: The document you quoted also appears to be outdated, or at least conflicts with the link in my answer, which says the limit is 25 MB.

Comment: The doc I quoted is the current (API 43) Apex Developer's Guide page on Apex Email Services.  I'll try the feedback link, hopefully it will get revised.  Nice catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [General email limits](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000271357&language=en_US&type=1) help, it specifies that there is a limit before each part of the message is truncated:

> Email body truncation size: 32 KB

If there are at least 32,000 characters in either body, then the appropriate flag will be set to true, and only the first 32,000 characters are passed in.

Comment: ...and helpfully NOT linked from the developer docs.  Yep, that's got to be it... any idea if that's a "flexible" limit with intervention from Salesforce?  Don't think 32KB will be an issue, but I expect the client to ask.

Comment: @JasonClark According to [this document](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1d0YrpwpeklFfexBxKnyFefZ6EaxQN42uK1PwEz5l0Hc/edit#gid=0) (not maintained by Salesforce, as far as I can tell), you can request an increase up to 131 KB.